# Detailed Help for Azure Powershell Cmdlets v1.x

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm running the following Azure powershell cmdlets:

```
PS C:\> (Get-Module -Name Azure).Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
1      0      1      -1

PS C:\> $psversiontable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      3.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34209
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.16481
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

I don't seem to be able to get any detailed help for the commands, only the bare bone parameters. For example:

```
PS C:\> Get-Help Get-AzureVNetConfig -detailed

NAME
    Get-AzureVNetConfig

SYNTAX
    Get-AzureVNetConfig [-ExportToFile <string>] [-Profile <AzureSMProfile>]  [<CommonParameters>]


PARAMETERS
    -ExportToFile <string>

    -Profile <AzureSMProfile>

    <CommonParameters>
        This cmdlet supports the common parameters: Verbose, Debug,
        ErrorAction, ErrorVariable, WarningAction, WarningVariable,
        OutBuffer and OutVariable. For more information, see
        about_CommonParameters (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113216).


ALIASES
    None


REMARKS
    None
```

Is it normal not to have a detailed help with examples, as it is common with other powershell modules ? It has happened to me on more than one machine.

In the [online documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/), in the Getting Help section does not mention any limitation.

I tried `Update-Help` but with no luck.

Thanks.

> Update: I have upgraded to the latest version ([1.0.2)](http://aka.ms/azure-powershellget) but still
>   the same behavior. The strange thing is that by looking at one help
>   example on this [page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/1377), the same command "New-AzureVMConfig" on my
>   machine is less detailed and with a different description from what is reported there. For example,
>   the parameter `-InstanceSize <String>` which is thoroughly described
>   in that page, in "my" version reports just he following information:
>
> ```
> -InstanceSize <string>
>     Represents the size of the machine.
>
>     Required?                    true
>     Position?                    1
>     Accept pipeline input?       true (ByPropertyName)
>     Parameter set name           (All)
>     Aliases                      None
>     Dynamic?                     false
> ```
>
> I understand that this could be due to different azure module versions,
>   still I never seem to have gotten the one with all the details.
>
> Does everybody else get the same level of details as that reported by
>   [singhkay] in his example [3](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/1377) for the same command ?

Comment: try again with the `-full` switch

Comment: thanks @Colyn1337 but unfortunately it does not make a difference. I do get the full help "template" but still without any detail. I wonder if it's just me or if it's the Azure powershell module that is kept to the bare minimum since it's an ongoing product and they prefer to keep the documentation on the web pages.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately the Azure cmdlets are really light on documentation. That said, the latest version as of writing this is 1.0.2 so you should probably update to that to get the latest help. Azure doesn't support update-help, you can verify this by checking the HelpInfoUri value (empty):

```
get-module azure | Select HelpInfoUri
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have this problem when I run exactly the same command from my laptop, so I think you need to install the latest azure powershell cmdlets (2.8 at the time of writing) at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/ (look for the powershell option).  also all cmdlet help is on MSDN

Comment: I have edited my question to include some other tests done after updating to the latest version (BTW: 2.8 is the SDK version, not the powershell version but I understand what you meant).